# Removing unwanted vertical scrollbar in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

In Internet Explorer 11 (other browsers don't have this issue), the below code shows an unwanted vertical scrollbar in the header.

[image: Gridview Header]

Using the Developer tools, you can see that the blue line below is overriding my '!important' override just two lines above

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to hide this scrollbar?  My first try was putting this same code into a stylesheet and that didn't help either (just letting you know that I have tried both ways).  Somehow the code that the browser generates is always putting that -ms-overflow-y: visible  code in everytime!  I've also tried putting in the following line in my code behind:  `gvHeaders.Style.Add("overflow-y", "hidden !important")`.  I've also tried putting the `noOverflowy` CssClass in the CoolGridView tag.  This is an ASP.NET page using C#.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Width="942px" Style="margin-left: 10px" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div id="HeaderDiv" runat="server" style="overflow-y: hidden !important" >
        <cool:CoolGridView ID="gvHeaders" runat="server"
            AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#FAFAFA" Width="929px"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="SortOrders"
            OnRowCommand="gvOrders_RowCommand" EmptyDataText="No Data to Display"
            OnRowDataBound="gvHeaders_RowDataBound"
            DataKeyNames="Id" HeaderStyle-Height="25px" BorderStyle="None"
            FixHeaders="True" EnableViewState="true">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"/>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" CssClass="craig"/>
            <BoundaryStyle BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="LightGray" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="LightGray" Height="25px" Font-Size="11" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Gray" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB"  Height="22px" CssClass="craig"/>
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Open">
                    <ItemTemplate>
```

...

I have added the `overflowHidden` function below to the `AutoExtend.js` file that is included with below `ScriptManagerProxy`.

```
function overflowHidden() {
    document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_UCOrdersControl_gvHeadersjEsCoOl_headerDiv').style.msOverflow = 'hidden';
}

<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server" >
    <Scripts>
       <asp:ScriptReference Path="../common/script/AutoExtend.js"/>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

As this is part of a master page, I have to use this `ScriptManagerProxy` tag, right?  The HTML still isn't getting changed.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Width="942px" Style="margin-left: 10px" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                overflowHidden();
            });
        </script>
    <div id="HeaderDiv" runat="server" >
        <cool:CoolGridView ID="gvHeaders" runat="server"
```

If I replace the above `overflowHidden()` function with alert("hellow world"); I do get this message, however, using above all I get is a JavaScript runtime error:

> 'overflowHiden' is undefined.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Width="942px" Style="margin-left: 10px" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                alert("About to set msOverFlow style to hidden");
                document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_UCOrdersControl_gvHeadersjEsCoOl_headerDiv').style.msOverflow = 'hidden';
            });
        </script>
    <div id="HeaderDiv" runat="server" >
        <cool:CoolGridView ID="gvHeaders" runat="server"
        ...
```

Here's my latest attempt above.  I do get the alert popup, but the rendered HTML stays the same.

Comment: Can you change the height of the header bar? Try increasing it a small amount

Comment: Thats an MS specific css rule, your `overflow-y` will just be ignored. Try adding `-ms-overflow-y: hidden !important;` instead.

Comment: Changing the size of my HeaderStyle from 25px to 35px simply made it and the scrollbar taller!  Changing to -ms-overflow-y didn't seem to have any effect either.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to server control rendering in ASP.NET, there is no much you can do except checking out thoroughly the documentation of the control in use in order to modify its layout (BTY this lack of control over the resulting HTML is one of the leading reasons for switching to ASP.NET MVC). However, you can always hack the generated HTML by JavaScript. So yo can do something like:

```
(function() {
   document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_UCOrdersControl_gvHeadersjEsCoOl_headerDiv').style.msOverflow = 'hidden';
})();
```

Comment: I`m sure the above might do exactly what I`m looking for, however, not being a javascript guru, how/where would I call such a script.  It has to be called after the page is rendered, right?

Comment: Yes, just place the script I mentioned in a script tag in the aspx page: `<script type="text/javascript">/* Here is the script */</script>`

Comment: You need to call that `overflowHidden()` anyway. As I mentioned, you can call it using `(function () { overflowHidden(); } )();` or search for jquery ready function in order to run script on page load. Put an `alert('test')` to see if the script is getting executed.

Comment: I have put the last suggestion/comments up above.

Comment: Try to put `overflowHidden()` function body within the same script tag of  `$(function()`

Comment: My latest try above.  Is this what you wanted me to try?

Comment: No, still didn't help.  Dang!